# Abrir dados do MySQL em outra página

Tags: php, html, mysql

Comecei a mexer em MySQL a pouco tempo e estou com um pequeno problema e não sei como resolver. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.
Tenho um site de livros que mostra a foto do livro e abaixo da foto, tem informações. Ao clicar em informações, abre uma nova página com as informações só daquele livro. Mas esse é o problema... Do jeito que estou tentando fazer, mostra a informação de todos os livros cadastrados no banco e não sei como mostrar somente do livro que a pessoa quer ver.

Na pagina livros.php, mostra a foto do livro:

```
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="gallery-item">
                    <div class="gallery">
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <form class="form-inline" action="livros.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                                <input name="titulo" id="titulo" placeholder="Pesquisar por Título..." type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            </form>
                            <br>
                            <a class="list-group-item active"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> <span>GÊNEROS</span></a>
                            <?php do {  ?>
                            <a class="list-group-item" href="livros.php?genero=<?php echo utf8_encode($linhas_menu['id']); ?>"> 
                    <?php echo $linhas_menu['genero']; ?></a>

                    <?php } while ($linhas_menu = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_menu));  ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


             <?php do {  ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="gallery-item">
                    <div class="gallery">
                        <img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/livro/imagem/<?php echo $linhas['imagem_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas['imagem']; ?>">
                        <a href="download.php#features" target="_blank"><h6>Informação</h6></a>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <?php } while ($linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado));  ?>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

</section>
```

Já na página download.php, mostraria a informação só daquele livro:

```
        <!-- Sections -->
    <section id="features" class="sections lightbg">

        <div class="container text-center">

            <div class="heading-content">
                <h3>Informação</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- Example row of columns -->
            <div class="row">
                <?php do{ ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="features-content">
                        <img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/livro/imagem/<?php echo $linhas_livro['imagem_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas_livro['imagem']; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="features-content">

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row"><h4>Autor:</h4></th>
                              <td><?php echo $linhas_livro['autor']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row"><h4>Título:</h4></th>
                              <td><?php echo $linhas_livro['titulo']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row"><h4>Gênero:</h4></th>
                              <td><?php echo $linhas_livro['genero']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row"><h4>Sinopse:</h4></th>
                              <td colspan="2"><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas_livro['sinopse']); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2">╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="download-tabela" scope="row"><h4>Download:</h4></th>
                              <td colspan="2"><a href="Admin/app/webroot/files/livro/arquivo/<?php echo $linhas_livro['arquivo_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas_livro['arquivo']; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          <?php } while ($linhas_livro = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_livro));  ?>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->

    </section>
```

Tem algum jeito de fazer abrir a informação do livro pelo id dele? Por exemplo, clica no livro Harry Potter que no banco de dados é o id 3, e abre somente as informações daquele livro?

Agradeço muito se alguém puder me ajudar.
Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa colocar no `href` de cada link, da página `livros.php`, o id do livro a ser aberto (exibir informações). E receber esse `id` ná página `download.php`. Algo como

### Página `livros.php`

```
<a href="download.php?idlivro=3" target="_blank">
```

### Página `download.php`

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['idlivro'];
$resultado = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM livros WHERE id = ' . $id, $link_bd);
....
....
?>
```

### Aplicando ao seu código

#### página livros.php

```
<?php do {  ?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <div class="gallery">
        <img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/livro/imagem/<?php echo $linhas['imagem_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas['imagem']; ?>">
        <a href="download.php?idlivro=<?php echo $linhas['id'] ?>" target="_blank"><h6>Informação</h6></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } while ($linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado));  ?>
```

#### Página `download.php`

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['idlivro'];
$resultado_livro = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM livros WHERE id = ' . $id, $link_bd);
....
....
?>
```

### Melhorias

- Atualizar as funções `mysql_*`, já que foram removidas a partir da versão [7 do php](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php), para utilizar [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.mysqli.php) ou [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php).
- Você tambem deverial proteger seu código contra [injeção de sql](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.
Vou tentar implementar aqui no meu site :)

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui puxar o livro pelo id.
Fiz como vc mencionou:

<?php
$id = $_GET['idlivro'];
$resultado_livro = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM livros WHERE id = ' . $id, $conn);
$linhas_livro = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_livro);
?>

<?php echo $linhas_livro['categoria']; ?>

Mas quando eu clico para abrir outro livro, fica sempre a mesma foto e as mesmas informações em todos, não muda.
Nao sei mais o que fazer.